# Compare two lists and add the difference to third list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists one called `currentHourList` and the other called `item.DealerOperatingHourList`.

My goal is to create a third list called `removedHours` where it compares the `currentHourList` to the `item.DealerOperatingHourList` and adds the items that have are in the `currentHourList` but not in the `item.DealerOperatingHourList`.

I'm sure that is confusing, so here is an example of what I would like the lists to be

```
**Current Hour List**
OperatingHourID
----
80
81
82
83

**DealerOperatingHour List**
OperatingHourID
----
80
81    
83

**Removed Hour List**
OperatingHourID
----
82
```

I've tried using this LINQ statement:

```
var removedHours = currentHourList.Where(m => !item.DealerOperatingHourList.Select(l => l.OperatingHourID).Contains(m.OperatingHourID));
```

But the results are always null. Not sure why, because this has worked for similar situations in my project.

### Edit

My code did actually work, the error was in a different part of my application

Answer (score 1):

You need the [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) function :

```
var removedHours = currentHourList.Except(item.DealerOperatingHourList)
```

Comment: But remember, that your object should implement Equals method or IEquality interface, because otherwise Except won't know how to compare it based on this field

Comment: I've suggested that both lists where List<int>

Answer (score 1):

And just as another idea, you can use Except method as AlexH suggested, but you can also implement IEqualityComparer like this:

```
public class HourListComparer : IEqualityComparer<Hour>
{
    public bool Equals(Hour x, Hour y)
    {
        return x != null && y != null && x.OperatingHourID == y.OperatingHourID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Hour obj)
    {
        return obj.OperatingHourID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Hour in that sample, is that your custom object from HourListComparer object.
And then use like this:

```
var removedHours = currentHourList.
      Except(item.DealerOperatingHourList, new HourListComparer());
```

Comment: The `GetHashCode` that you have provided does not use the same definition of equality as the `Equals` method, so that comparer will not work.

Answer (score 0):

My above code did acutally work:

```
var removedHours = currentHourList.Where(m => !item.DealerOperatingHourList.Select(l => l.OperatingHourID).Contains(m.OperatingHourID));
```

I discovered the error somewhere else in my application.